# format query in postgres

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

```
    $query1 = pg_query('SELECT "id","location",ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_Point(lat,long ), ST_Centroid("path"::geometry)) FROM places 
        ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere
        LIMIT 1');

echo $query1
```

i have a database with lat and long coardinates in, and if i run the above query in the phpPgAdmin it gives me the desired result, but when querying through php its not, its giving me "resource 7" instead

have i formatted the query above correctly?

thanks in advance AJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is echo $query1

You cannot just echo the result. First you have to declare a connection and then You have to do something with it in order to print it out. eg:

```
$con = pg_connect("host=you_host_db port=5432 dbname=database_name");

$query1 = pg_query($con, 'SELECT "id","location",ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_Point(lat,long ) as a,ST_Centroid("path"::geometry)) as b FROM places ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere LIMIT 1');


while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['location'];
    echo $row['a'];
    echo $row['b'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell whether a SQL statement is formatted correctly by assigning it to a variable, then echoing out the value of the variable.  You need to echo the SQL statement, not the value returned by pg_query().

```
$ cat code/php/test.php
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT "id","location",ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_Point(lat,long ), ST_Centroid("path"::geometry)) FROM places ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere LIMIT 1';
echo $sql;
$  php code/php/test.php
SELECT "id","location",ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_Point(lat,long ), ST_Centroid("path"::geometry)) FROM places ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere LIMIT 1%                  ➜  ~
```

The order of arguments to ST_Point() is "long, lat", not "lat, long". If your original query returns the right results, I'd be mildly worried.